# Need help saving and continuing user input

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, encryption

I am trying to create a word game that can encrypt a word and shift the characters a certain number by what the user inputs, decrypt that encryption, and check if the word is a palindrome. The problem is I do not know how to keep the input going, so after i encrypt or check if it is a palindrome the program ends so i cannot decrypt what has been encrypted.

For example-If the user inputs the word "hello" and selects to encrypt the word, with a key of 3 it should display "khoor." Then i would like to be able to continue by decrypting "khoor" back to "hello" but the program ends.

Also the when the user inputs a key number, the characters shift 7 more characters than the input number.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WordPlayTester{

public static void main(String [] args){

String word, reverse="";
String original;
int key= 0;
String Menu= "1-Encrypt \n2-Decrypt \n3-Is Palindrome \n0-Quit \n-Select an option-";

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("-Type any word-");
      String toUpperCase;
      word = in.nextLine();
System.out.println(Menu);

   int choice=in.nextInt();
   if(choice==1)
   {
  System.out.println("Insert a Key number");
   int select= in.nextInt();


      for (int i=0; i < word.length(); i++) {
         char c = word.charAt(i);
         if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'z') {
            c = (char)(c - 65);
            int n = c+select;
            n = n % 26;
            if (n < 0) {
               n = n + 26;
            }
            c = (char)(n + 65);
         }
         System.out.print(c);
      }
      }
      else if(choice==2)
   {
  System.out.println("Insert a Key number");
   int select2= in.nextInt();


      for (int i=0; i < word.length(); i++) {
         char c = word.charAt(i);
         if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'z') {
            c = (char)(c - 65);
            int n = c+select2;
            n = n % 26;
            if (n < 0) {
               n = n - 26;
            }
            c = (char)(n - 65);
         }
         System.out.print(c);

      }
      if(key==0)
      {
      System.out.println("Word has not been encrypted yet.");
      }

}



   else if(choice==3)
   {
   int length = word.length();
      for ( int i = length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i-- )
         reverse = reverse + word.charAt(i);
      if (word.equals(reverse))
         System.out.println("Your word is a palindrome.");
      else
         System.out.println("Your word is not a palindrome.");


      }
      else if(choice==0)
      {
      System.exit(0);
      }

     else 
      {
      System.out.println(Menu);
      }

   }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Put your logic in a do-while loop starting from first input. Then at the end use a variable to decide when to quit.

```
String isExit = "N";
do{
    System.out.println("-Type any word-");
    String toUpperCase;
    word = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println(Menu);
.
.
.
.
System.out.println("-Exit? Y/N-");
    isExit = in.nextLine();

}while(!isExit.equals("Y"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a do-while loop

```
do{
   //your logic
}while(choice!=0);
```